# Parsing a floating point number with mantissa in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double, bigdecimal, mantissa

Using the standard Java `Double` class to parse a floating point number with mantissa seems to omit the + sign from the exponent.

For example:

```
Double.parseDouble("1258124354E-28") returns 1.258124354E-19, but
Double.parseDouble("1243544322E+24") returns 1.243544322E33 (not E+33)
```

Is there any way to get the + sign using Double, without string post-processing?

The `BigDecimal` class does a better job, e.g.

```
new BigDecimal("1243544322E+24").toString() does return 1.243544322E+33
```

but it is generally slower than `Double`, which shows in intensive processing.

Comment: Don't print it with toString, use an instance of NumberFormat.

Answer (score 6):

You need to differentiate between the *value* stored in a `double` and its string representation.

A `double` doesn't store a textual representation at all. 1.243544322E33 *is* 1.243544322E+33. They're the same value.

Now if you want to work on how you *format* a `double` value back to a `String`, that's a different matter - but the *parsing* you're doing is fine. You're not losing any information.

Comment: Sure. I wasn't worried that information is lost, it is just that the + sign is necessary for my application.

Answer (score 2):

Jon is correct as above, its representing it correctly in memory. If you want it to display with the + on the mantissa then you are talking about string formatting the double.

[Long winded official formatter reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#l10n%20algorithm)

```
import java.util.Formatter;

double myDouble = Double.parseDouble("1243544322E+24");

Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
formatter.format("%+E", myDouble); //This should return with what you want, though with an extra + infront of the number
```

I haven't ran this code so I'm not 100% sure it will do the job. The + in the format specifier forces it to place a + or - sign for any number... I believe that extends to the mantissa.